# Click listener in RecyclerView

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I had used `RecyclerView` several times and also handled click listeners. But my question is that in `RecyclerView Adapter` at which place setting the click listener is better, like in `onCreateViewHolder()` or `onBindViewHolder()` or in `ViewHolder` class. Because, I know at any place we set we can achieve our functionality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick

Comment: @sumitsingh I know this but as per my question which place will be better.

Answer (score 2):

You can set click listener for multiple views in your container view for various purposes. Best approach if it is an item click to add listener to container view :

```
private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.containerViewItem, parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
```

And implement `onClick()` method for your `mOnClickListener` .

Comment: I know this types of implementation but which will be better as per my question?

Answer (score 1):

The  onBindViewHolder method  is called every time when you bind your view with data.So the best place is to set click listener inside onCreateViewHolder method.

```
 private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();

 @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final  int position) 
      {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recycler_list_item, parent, false);
       view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
       return new ViewHolder(view);
     }

 @Override
 public void onClick(final View view) {

      }
```